# How to use query strings

Tags: php, json

I have a php file with JSON [here](http://wowsk.org/comments/comments.php) and I want to use a query string at the end of my url to find the comment with id 1 for example. I think it should look something like this:

> http://wowsk.org/comments/comments.php?id=1

This does not work though and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have never worked with query strings so I can't say that I will understand right away what your solution is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please give us your php code.

Comment: The link "here" is to the JSON php. Do I need php to use a query string?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Do you know anything about php?

Comment: How should I use this though? I am not very good with PHP.

Comment: Voting to close this as too broad, since I believe to properly answer this question will require much more than just talking about how PHP uses query strings. OP, how are you _storing_ these comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments.php file, you should look for the value in $_REQUEST['id'], and include this value in your sql query (if you are using sql database).
Also don't forget about SQL injection, so at least use an intval() on ID fields.